# Gremlin slow joinTime on Neptune

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I have an issue with a request performance in Neptune. I have a graph like this :

> hasId('A_id') (count: 1) -> out('has_group') (count: 12) -> out('has_class').hasLabel('C') (count: 9751) -> out('has_type').hasLabel('D') (count: 9749) ->
> out('has_element') (count: 472370) ->  hasLabel(Within(11 elements label)) (count: 107233)

I replace all the label to simplify, but the graph is exactly like this. The within decrease a lot the performance of the query. For more details :

```
g.V('0f7a21df-9413-4c71-99f3-242ae25356a5').out('has_group').out('has_class').hasLabel('C').out('has_type').hasLabel('D').out('has_element').count()
```

This request take less than 1 secondes and return 472370.

If I add the last hasLabel(whithin()) like this :

```
g.V('0f7a21df-9413-4c71-99f3-242ae25356a5').out('has_group').out('has_class').hasLabel('C').out('has_type').hasLabel('D').out('has_element').hasLabel(P.within('element_1','element_2','element_3','element_4','element_5','element_6','element_7','element_8','element_9','element_10','element_11')).count()
```

The time decrease to 18 seconds. And when I profile the query we can see a joinTime which take at least 90% of the query execution time on the within :

```
Optimized Traversal
===================
Neptune steps: [
    NeptuneCountGlobalStep {
        JoinGroupNode {
            PatternNode[(?1=<0f7a21df-9413-4c71-99f3-242ae25356a5>, ?5=<has_group>, ?3, ?6) . project ?1,?3 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?6) .
            ],
            {estimatedCardinality=12, expectedTotalOutput=12, indexTime=0, joinTime=1, numSearches=1, actualTotalOutput=12
            }
            PatternNode[(?3, ?9=<has_class>, ?7, ?10) . project ?3,?7 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?10) .
            ],
            {estimatedCardinality=208482, expectedTotalOutput=2000, indexTime=0, joinTime=9, numSearches=1, actualTotalOutput=10945
            }
            PatternNode[(?7, <~label>, ?8=<C>, <~>) . project ask .
            ],
            {estimatedCardinality=424296, expectedTotalOutput=2000, indexTime=5, joinTime=111, numSearches=10945, actualTotalOutput=9751
            }
            PatternNode[(?7, ?13=<has_type>, ?11, ?14) . project ?7,?11 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?14) .
            ],
            {estimatedCardinality=9675934, expectedTotalOutput=11695, indexTime=15, joinTime=95, numSearches=10, actualTotalOutput=42226
            }
            PatternNode[(?11, <~label>, ?12=<D>, <~>) . project ask .
            ],
            {estimatedCardinality=2333386, expectedTotalOutput=11695, indexTime=23, joinTime=402, numSearches=42226, actualTotalOutput=9749
            }
            PatternNode[(?11, ?17=<has_element>, ?15, ?18) . project ?11,?15 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?18) .
            ],
            {estimatedCardinality=8562896, expectedTotalOutput=556904, indexTime=18, joinTime=442, numSearches=10, actualTotalOutput=472370
            }
            PatternNode[(?15, <~label>, ?16, <~>) . project ask . ContainsFilter(?16 in (<element_1>, <element_2>, <element_3>, <element_4>, <element_5>, <element_6>, <element_7>, <element_8>, <element_9>, <element_10>, <element_11>)) .
            ],
            {estimatedCardinality=1158922, indexTime=598, joinTime=18991, numSearches=472370
            }
        }, annotations={path=[Vertex(?1):GraphStep, Vertex(?3):VertexStep, Vertex(?7):VertexStep, Vertex(?11):VertexStep, Vertex(?15):VertexStep
            ], joinStats=true, optimizationTime=1, maxVarId=19, executionTime=20799
        }
    }
]
```

The request seems quite simple and the volume not that much. The within is not the good approach here ? Do you have some clue to improve the query ?

**EDIT 1:**

I tried with the request provided by @saikiranboga and the number of index operation is large better (divided by 10) but the join time is still high. I'm quite confuse.

The index operation number before :

```
Index Operations
================
Query execution:
    # of statement index ops: 525563
    # of unique statement index ops: 525563
    Duplication ratio: 1.0
    # of terms materialized: 0
```

and after

```
Index Operations
================
Query execution:
    # of statement index ops: 53666
    # of unique statement index ops: 53666
    Duplication ratio: 1.0
    # of terms materialized: 0
```

```
Optimized Traversal
===================
Neptune steps: [
    NeptuneCountGlobalStep {
        JoinGroupNode {
            PatternNode[(?1=<0f7a21df-9413-4c71-99f3-242ae25356a5>, ?5=<has_group>, ?3, ?6) . project ?1,?3 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?6) .
            ],
            {estimatedCardinality=12, expectedTotalOutput=12, indexTime=0, joinTime=0, numSearches=1, actualTotalOutput=12
            }
            PatternNode[(?3, ?9=<has_class>, ?7, ?10) . project ?3,?7 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?10) .
            ],
            {estimatedCardinality=208000, expectedTotalOutput=2000, indexTime=0, joinTime=10, numSearches=1, actualTotalOutput=10945
            }
            PatternNode[(?7, <~label>, ?8=<C>, <~>) . project ask .
            ],
            {estimatedCardinality=424296, expectedTotalOutput=2000, indexTime=4, joinTime=102, numSearches=10945, actualTotalOutput=9751
            }
            PatternNode[(?7, ?13=<has_type>, ?11, ?14) . project ?7,?11 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?14) .
            ],
            {estimatedCardinality=9456689, expectedTotalOutput=11695, indexTime=13, joinTime=94, numSearches=10, actualTotalOutput=42226
            }
            PatternNode[(?11, <~label>, ?12=<D>, <~>) . project ask .
            ],
            {estimatedCardinality=2333386, expectedTotalOutput=11695, indexTime=17, joinTime=341, numSearches=42226, actualTotalOutput=9749
            }
            PatternNode[(?11, ?17=<has_element>, ?15, ?18) . project ?11,?15 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?18) .
            ],
            {estimatedCardinality=7919022, expectedTotalOutput=556904, indexTime=17, joinTime=411, numSearches=10, actualTotalOutput=472370
            }
            PatternNode[(?15, <~label>, ?16, <~>) . project ?16 . ContainsFilter(?16 in (<element_1>, <element_2>, <element_3>, <element_4>, <element_5>, <element_6>, <element_7>, <element_8>, <element_9>, <element_10>, <element_11>)) .
            ],
            {estimatedCardinality=1145096, indexTime=848, joinTime=15268, numSearches=473
            }
        }, finishers=[dedup(?15)
        ], annotations={path=[Vertex(?1):GraphStep, Vertex(?3):VertexStep, Vertex(?7):VertexStep, Vertex(?11):VertexStep, Vertex(?15):VertexStep@[element
                ], VertexLabel(?16):LabelStep
            ], joinStats=true, optimizationTime=1, maxVarId=19, executionTime=17283
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your observation is correct, the last pattern is indeed what is taking more time in the query. "ask" projections usually involve multiple index look ups and could cause slowness, these are usually optimized by the database, but it is not in this case.

Could you try a rewritten version of the query that fetches the labels and filters them instead of the hasLabel(...) filter, like below:

```
g.V('0f7a21df-9413-4c71-99f3-242ae25356a5')
.out('has_group').out('has_class').hasLabel('C')
.out('has_type').hasLabel('D')
.out('has_element').as("element")
.label().is(
  within(
    'element_1','element_2','element_3','element_4','element_5',
    'element_6','element_7','element_8','element_9','element_10','element_11'
  )
)
.dedup("element")
.count()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I edit the question to include the test with your request. The index operations is large better (divided by 10) but the join time is still high, not really logic. What the "project ask" mean ? Why the number of operation involve ? I just want to understand to progress. Because projection for me is only when we use select/values/project/...

Comment: "project ask" is an indication for the runtime to project boolean result for the index search and is a bit limited on how the execution is performed. With ask projection, the physical operators would issue a single index operation to the storage per incoming solution and hence you see high index operations before.  With the rewrite, the physical operator would be combing multiple incoming solutions and issue a single batch index operation to the storage.

Comment: projection in this case is an indication of return values from the index search on storage. For example, "project ?1,?3" in first PatternNode indicates that matching values for variables ?1 and ?3 would be returned from the storage search.

Comment: Do you get same performance if you run the query multiple times? If it runs faster for subsequent runs it could indicate that the instance might be warming up.

If this still does not help, I would suggest reaching out to AWS Support for Neptune to take a look at this case. Neptune also supports a new DFE engine which might help https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/gremlin-with-dfe.html

Comment: I try to run the query multiple times, and the time was constant. I send an email to the support. Thank you for your help and explanation. I understand better how the query is executed now.